# Javascript: synchronization code

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I am writing a verification script to set fields using JQuery and then verify their persistence to a JSON blob.  For text fields there are no issues but with calendars, which require some wait time, I run into trouble.  NOTE: I am not using Selenium because the goal is to create a faster alternative.

Sample code:
    // setCalendars is a jQuery wrapper

```
test1 = function()
{
  loadPage();
  setTimeout(function() 
  { 
    setCalendars(fromDate, toDate);
    setTimeout(function()
      {
         assertEqual(fromDate, blob.fromDate);
         assertEqual(toDate, blob.toDate);
      }
      , INTERVAL);
   }
   , INTERVAL);   
}
```

The problem is that test2, test3 begin executing before the calendar fields are set and a mess is created.

Please Advise

Comment: it will be better if you can use some kind of callback mechanism instead of depending of timers

Comment: also share the code inside setCalendars

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the library [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) by Tim Caswell, it is specifically designed for serializing callback execution.

Your code above would turn into something like:

```
test1 = function()
{
  Step(
    loadPage,
    function () {
      setCalendars(fromDate, toDate);
      this(); // triggers the next step
    },
    function () {
      assertEqual(fromDate, blob.fromDate);
      assertEqual(toDate, blob.toDate);
    }
  )
}
```

With `Step` you have careful control over what gets executed when.

If you modify your code to have callbacks for when each step is completed, you could modify the code to something like this:

```
test1 = function()
{
  Step(
    loadPage(this),
    function () {
      setCalendars(fromDate, toDate, this);
    },
    function () {
      assertEqual(fromDate, blob.fromDate);
      assertEqual(toDate, blob.toDate);
    }
  )
}
```

Note that `this` within the context of `Step` is the callback that triggers the next 'step' in the sequence.

Hope that helps,
Aaron